# Unable to connect to remote Oracle DB from an Azure Cloud Service

Tags: oracle, azure, azure-web-roles

We are trying to deploy a Web Service on Azure Cloud Services that needs to access a remote Oracle DB.

We keep getting the following error when testing the connection:

> System.Data.OracleClient 8.1.7 or greater required.

Here's the part of the code that we are using to connect:

```
using System.Data.OracleClient;

public string InsertUser_NOHA_UTENTI_Oracle(string cognome, string nome, string email)
    {
        string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings css = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbOracle"];
        string query = "INSERT INTO NOHA_UTENTI (COGNOME,NOME,MAIL,TOKEN,STATO,DT_ISCRIZ,DT_CONF_ISCRIZ) values (@cognome, @nome, @email, @token, @stato, @dataIscrizione, @dataConfermaIscrizione)";

        try
        {
            // create connection and command
            using (OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xx.xx.xx.xx)(PORT=xxxx))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)));User Id=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxx;"))
            {
                using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, cn))
                {
                    // define parameters and their values
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@cognome", OracleType.VarChar, 50).Value = cognome;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@nome", OracleType.VarChar, 50).Value = nome;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", OracleType.VarChar, 50).Value = email;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@token", OracleType.VarChar, 50).Value = guid;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@stato", OracleType.VarChar, 1).Value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["statoInAttesa"];
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@dataIscrizione", OracleType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@dataConfermaIscrizione", OracleType.DateTime).Value = null;

                    // open connection, execute INSERT, close connection
                    cn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cn.Close();

                    return guid;

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

We tried to follow these solutions unsuccessfully:

http://www.splinter.com.au/using-the-new-odpnet-to-access-oracle-from-c/

http://omegacoder.com/?p=445

Could someone who has successfully deployed a similar application on Azure point us in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And have you tried to install Oracle Client version 8.1.7 or greater?

Comment: On the Azure Web Role? How would that work?

Comment: Wait, who owns the Oracle DB server?

Comment: The Oracle DB Server is at a customer's site and we have no control over it.